# Remove index.php Cake PHP from url

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

I'm new to CAKEPHP . I copied the files from the server and imported to localhost. The css and images didnt loaded. I uncommented the 
Configure::write(‘App.baseUrl’, env(‘SCRIPT_NAME’)); and now website is displaying but the url includes index.php.

Comment: make sure Apache mode_rewrite is enabled

Comment: Apache mode_rewrite is enabled. Htaccess is the problem. I downloaded the new cakephp and copied that htaccess and now its working. Thanks

Comment: retag your question correctly, it's impossible your using both 1.3 and 2.0 version at the same time, what is your exact version? Also, if you think .htaccess is the problem, post it in the question, even if it is cake's same installation htaccess, the question should contain all pertinent info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) open " **mod_rewrite** " from apache server.

2) comment " **Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));** " this line from /confige/core.php

Comment: I finished 2 steps , but when i upload them to Centos server, url also include index.php

Comment: You have to restart apache server.